# Best Interpolation for grayscale segmentation mask

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

Suppose I need to resize grayscale segmentation mask which contains only two colors: 255 and 0. The resize itself in my case can be applied both for downscaling and upscaling the mask.

[image]

For example,`cv2.INRER_AREA` interpolation sometimes can color pixels in `254,253` color near the white area, and put `2,3,4...` near black area. 
Which interpolation should be used to obtain a resulting mask without but keep the colors I need?

Or It's better to mark all white pixels with 1, i.e. to use a binary/bolean mask?

Comment: You generally use NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR if you want to avoid introducing new values when resizing. This is especially true with classification images where interpolating between wheat and forest classes might result in sea !

Comment: Take a look at [What is OpenCV’s INTER_AREA Actually Doing?](https://medium.com/@wenrudong/what-is-opencvs-inter-area-actually-doing-282a626a09b3) for a really great explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two values anyway, pay attention if you use the `bool` dtype, as not all image processing operations will be supported. 
Something that is both easy and fast is to filter your image with a median filter to fill in gaps. (This is admittedly a little lazy but has produced good results for me in the past).

If you want to interpolate with your `uint8` range, maybe thresholding afterwards will do the trick for your.

Edit:
This is what a median filter produces:

[image: Median filtered]

Comment: Thank you, @code-lukas. That's a really good and simple technique to make segmentation mask more smooth after resizing It with INTER_NEAREST.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad we could solve this! If you need any help just let me know

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest **cv2.INTER_BITS**.

You can try to calculate DICE coefficient with the new mask(upsampled->downsampled to original shape) to see how good is your interpolation method.

Comment: There is no such interpolation in Python OpenCV according to https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121ac97d8e4880d8b5d509e96825c7522deb

Comment: It is there, right under InterpolationMasks

Comment: OK. I see now. I was looking at InterpolationFlags